# Whats the best way to create bathymetric contour lines?

Tags: raster, dem, contour, bathymetry, lakes

I have a raster dataset with both Topographic and Bathymetric stored in it. What is the best way to create exact contours of the lake-bed? This becomes tricky when I want to make the contour for depth = "zero", when in fact it is not as easy as it seems, since I get contour out of the lake "boundary". Then the question becomes how we really define a lake boundary.

Thanks

P.S. I'm using ArcGIS-10.1 and model builder.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?  You can use the edit button beneath it to revise your Question with this important detail.